# How to extract data from .docx .pages?

Tags: objective-c, ms-word, doc

I'm trying to get all data from .docx .pages files like this:
(i need to extract phone number, picture and some more information)

```
    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FileName" ofType:@"pages"];
NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding error:NULL];
for (NSString *line in [fileContents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", line);
}
```

Can someone help me to solve this isue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **apache poi** (it is open source ) for extracting data from docx.

Comment: Thank you, i will try it soon. Maybe you can recommend any guide ? :)

Comment: A docx has own ".xml" format . then u can retrive your information from that xml .You can follow this step 1)Read the docx file
2)Unzip it
3)Get The Contents of the 'word/document.xml' file